# Python добавление текста при нажатии клавиши

Tags: python, list, tkinter

Хочу сделать чтобы когда нажимаешь в окне TKinter букву "a". И он добавлял эту букву к переменной `code`.
Вот мой код:

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()

code = ""

def add_word(text):
    return code + text

root.bind("a", print(add_word("a")))

root.mainloop()
```

При этом ничего не получается. Думаю, идея понятна. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: `code=tkinter.StringVar()` для текстовых переменных

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В методе `bind` вы не можете вызывать функцию. вы можете передавать её имя. А функцию `print` вы именно вызываете. Если вы хотите передать аргументы в функцию, то должны представлять функцию через `lambda`.

надо так:

```py
root.bind("a", lambda t: add_word(t))
```

Comment: Спасибо.  А как мне теперь посмотреть значение переменной code? Через print(code) не работает

Comment: @Rodion, если этот ответ решил вопрос, отметьте его как [**принятый**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) (галка напротив ответа).

Comment: @Rodion, Если у вас есть другие вопросы, вы можете задать их нажав кнопку [«Задать вопрос»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).